# Test convergence of the series $\sum(2\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n})$

Tags: convergence-divergence

$$\sum(2\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n})$$

I have tried comparison test but gives the best I get was $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Comment: You should compute some partial sums and see what you get.  The sum telescopes so you should get something fairly simple (the exact expression depends on the lower limit of the sum—I'm assuming $n = 1$, but it could be something else).

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Write as $$(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})+(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n+2})$$ and combine each term  using the conjugate.

Comment: gives me only $\frac{1}{n}$ , so still nothing

Comment: @TheMeff Not true, if you proceed carefully as vadim123 indicated, you should get that the general term is $$\frac2{(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}$$ from which the  conclusion is direct.

Answer (score 3):

$$2\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt n=(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)-(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})=f(n)-f(n+1)$$ where $f(m)=\sqrt{m+1}-\sqrt m$

Partial Sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^r(2\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt n)=\sum_{n=1}^r(f(n)-f(n+1))=\cdots=f(1)-f(r+1)$$

Now  $f(m)=\sqrt{m+1}-\sqrt m=\dfrac{m+1-m}{\sqrt m+\sqrt{(m+1)}}$

Answer (score 0):

Just follow Brian Tung's hint:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left[(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})-(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})\right] = (\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1})-(\sqrt{N+2}-\sqrt{N+1}) $$
then notice that $0\leq\sqrt{N+2}-\sqrt{N+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N+1}+\sqrt{N+2}}\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{N}}$.